# Issue with React Infinite Scroll - not fetching more data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

Hello I am working on a page that pulls a list of items from a sanity.io data store and trying to show 10 at time using infinite scroll to render an additional 10 each time they go down. However, the issue I am having is that only the first 10 items show, and it doesn't seem that the fetchNextPages function is getting called. I've been racking my brain on this one for several hours any help appreciated

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { client } from "../client";
import MasonryLayout from "./MasonryLayout";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import { feedQuery, searchQuery } from "../utils/data";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const Feed = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { categoryId } = useParams();
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
  const [firstId, setFirstId] = useState(10);
  const [lastId, setLastId] = useState(20);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    if (categoryId) {
      const query = searchQuery(categoryId);
      client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    } else {
      client.fetch(feedQuery).then((data) => {
        setItems(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [categoryId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPages(items?.slice(0, 10));
  }, [items]);


  const fetchNextPage = () => {
    const result = items.slice(firstId, lastId);
    setPages([...pages, ...result]);
    if (result.length===0 || result.length < 10) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    setFirstId(firstId + 10);
    setLastId(lastId + 10);
  };

  if (loading) return <Spinner message="Searching for items...!" />;
  if (!pages?.length) return <h2>No results available.</h2>;

  return (
    <InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={pages?.length}
      next={fetchNextPage}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      loader={
        <Spinner
          message="Searching for items..."
          endMessage={
            <p className="align-center font-extrabold">End of list.</p>
          }
        />
      }
    >
      <div>
        <div className="mt-4 bm-4 w-full rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg bg-slate-50 pl-2 pr-2 pt-4 pb-4">
          <p>Some information about this … </p>
        </div>
        {pages && <MasonryLayout items={pages} />}
      </div>
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
};
export default Feed;

 ​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey could you please change you code-

```
  const fetchNextPage = () => {
    const result = items.slice(firstId, lastId);
    setPages([...pages, ...result]);
    if (result.length===0 || result.length < 10) {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
    setFirstId(firstId + 10);
    setLastId(lastId + 10);
  };
```

with this one.. because I think there is an issue with your fetchNextPage-

```
const fetchNextPage = () => {
  const result = items.slice(firstId, lastId + 10);
  setPages([...pages, ...result]);
  if (result.length === 0 || result.length < 10) {
    setHasMore(false);
  }
  setFirstId(lastId + 1);
  setLastId(lastId + 10);
};
```

Please let me know if this works or not. I will help you more..!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response.  I tried your code but I am having the same issue, it appears the fetchNextPage is never getting called for some reason